Choose your own adventure style: medieval post-demon apocalypse
I had a book when I was younger, that was a choose your own adventure style, with an inventory in the front pages, and you would roll for your skills/attributes. You would roll dice during any encounters, but your choices could end up changing your stats.
I don't remember much as I think I was a little young to fully register what was going on, but I remember to arrive to a land you had been to before, possibly your childhood home country, and discover it has come under a demon attack and is currently in a post demon attack state.
I don't remember much beyond that other than finding a windmill with poisoned grain, and another part where you are walking down a road and there is a skeleton in a cage hanging on a post, and spoiler alert the skeleton comes to life and attacks you.

When were you "younger"?

@FuzzyBoots - I'm guessing before today

Sorry, this was in the mid/early 90's. The book was probably from the 80's

This is Dead of Night (Fighting Fantasy #40, 1989) by Jim Bambra and Stephen Hand.
This review mentions the demon attack and the need to cross a demon-infested land to get to your destination.

Your primary driver is to rescue your parents from the Demon Lord Myurr with whom you have had a long-running feud. He has now abducted your parents and wants to use them as the sacrifice in his demonic ritual to unleash himself and his nasty hordes on the land and generally ruin everything for everyone, and you have to travel from the South of Gallantaria to the North, passing through areas that show increased evidence of demonic infestation, to ultimately find Myurr’s stronghold and try to save your parents/the world before it’s too late.

The skeleton appears very early on. You see it in illustration and then it attacks you.


Drawing near the gibbet irons, you see that they are old and on the point
of collapse. The rope linking the cage with the wooden scaffold is
frayed and rotten and the cage itself is more rust than metal, and the
splintered scaffold is plagued with mould. Worse still, the festering
skeleton held by the iron bars is laughing! Its bony body judders and
thrashes within the restricting confines of the cage, and its skull
rocks with malevolent glee. Somehow it knows your name and, in a
gruff voice, it mocks you: 'You're too late, fool Your pathetic powers
cannot aid you now.'


THIS IS IT! Oh my gosh, thank you! The nostalgia will be flowing once I get my hands on this.

@Mason - There's a decrepit windmill (complete with a necromancer lying in ambush. Spoiler, go round the back :-), but I can't find anything about poisoned grain
